# Automatic routing filter rejected remote request - Nexus

Tags: maven, netty, nexus

I'm trying to get the netty-codec-hhtp going in my maven project. I have a completely standard  Sonatype Nexus set up to proxy requests to Maven Central.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This fails when building using maven. If I search for it manually in Nexus I find it, but if I go to download the jar it tells me:

```
404 - Not Found
Automatic routing filter rejected remote request for path /io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.0.9.Final/netty-codec-http-4.0.9.Final.jar from M2Repository(id=central)
```

What does this even mean, why am I getting it, and maybe more importantly, how do I fix it?
I am using Nexus 2.5.0-04 with Maven 3.0.4

Downloading other artifacts seems to work just fine.

Comment: How are you "downloading" the jar so you get that error message? And how up to date is your Central index and prefix file download? Also I know there were some automatic routing related fixed in recently releases so I would test with 2.6.3-01 and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This turned out to be an issue with CDN  configuration that should now be resolved. The steps below for forcing and/or disabling remote discovery are left for reference.

It means that Automatic Routing for Central is active, and that the discovered rules does not contain `io.jetty` as allowed prefix.

This should not happen, as the default configuration should update the rules on daily basis (as seen on screenshot below, showing the default Automatic Routing configuration for Central).

The remedy is to either force the update of rules (I did check, prefix `/io` is among rules Central publishes), or disable remote discovery completely.

Try steps as shown below on screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I had to disable Discovery even though it said successful.  Downloads immediately working.

Comment: This fixed the problem with my Gradle Plugins repo (proxy repository for https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)

Answer (score 1):

From [Repository Management with Nexus - 6.4. Managing Routing](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html#):

> Routing can be considered the internal activities Nexus perform in order to determine, where to look for a specific component in a Maven repository. The routing information has an impact on the performance of component retrieval as well as determining the availability of components. 
>   
> (...)
>  Automatic Routing is handled by Nexus on a per repository basis.
> (...)
> The Routing information consists of the top two levels of the directory structure of the repository and is stored in a prefixes.txt file. It allows Nexus to **automatically route only component requests with the corresponding groupId values to a repository to avoid unnecessary index or even remote repository access.**

Since Maven central repo [contains that artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.0.9.Final) I assume that the automatic routing rules forbids remote download for that artifact. The error message you posted suggests it also.

You can read how to add a routing rule under [6.4.2. Manual Routing Configuration](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html#manual-routing). If my assumption is correct, this situation shoud be resolved by adding an `inclusive` rule type with `^/io/netty/.*` route for central repo.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. If i bypass nexus it works fine, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having Nexus as a local proxy  in the first place. The most frustrating thing is that I can browse it just fine through nexus, but because it is "not locally cached" I get an error message instead.

I realize we can always just manually install the artifact into the nexus release repo manually, but that defeats the point even further.

Do I have to restart nexus or something for routing rules to take effect?

Comment: I don't have Nexus installed, but as much as I can remember it is not necessary to restart, a save should be enough. Do try however, you have nothing to lose. I agree that bypassing Nexus or installing manually is not the solution. You might try with an exclusive rule for local repos also.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when **configuring a bridge between 2 Nexus**.

In the first:

1. I added 2 proxy repo, targeting 2 public repo groups in the second,
2. then aggregate those 2 proxy repos in a new group,
3. that I finally added to the repo list of the first Nexus public repo group

Using the first Nexus, each time I requested a dependency only present in the 2nd, I encountered the `Automatic routing filter rejected remote request for path...` exception.

As mentionned by Tamas, this issue comes from the `Routing >> Discovery` feature that was enabled in my 2 proxy repos, that were targeting **remote Nexus repository groups**.
**Once disabled, the issue was solved**.

**The exact explanation of this need** is in some way explained in the official Sonatype documentation for [Repository Management with Nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/), in chapter 6.4.1 on Automatic Routing:

> The Routing tab for a proxy repository displayed in Figure 6.18,
>   “Automatic Routing for a Proxy Repository” contains the **Discovery
>   section**. It displays the Status and a more detailed Message about the
>   prefix file access. The Last run field displays the date and time of
>   the last execution of the prefix file discovery. Such an execution can
>   be triggered by pressing the Update now button. Otherwise, the Update
>   Interval allows you to trigger a new discovery every one, two, three,
>   six, nine or twelve hours or as a daily or weekly execution.
>
> [...]
>
> For a proxy repository, the prefix file is either downloaded from the
>   remote repository or a generation is attempted by scraping the remote
>   repository. **This generation is not attempted for remote *Nexus
>   repository groups*, since they are too dynamic in nature and should not
>   be proxied directly**. Scraping of hosted or proxy repositories as well
>   as Subversion-based repositories is supported.

Regards,
Thomas